# oneliner for add line to svn:ignore

Tags: bash, svn, svnignore

```
$ svn pg svn:ignore .
file1
file2
file3
$ svn pe svn:ignore .
// manually add file4 in default text editor
```

How to add `file4` to `svn:ignore` using bash in one line command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely not elegant but it works:

```
svn propget svn:ignore . > /tmp/svnproperties && echo "file4" >> /tmp/svnproperties && svn propset svn:ignore . --file /tmp/svnproperties
```